# How do I complete this proof that the absolute value of an integral function is an integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I'm trying to complete the proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/316095/93114) that if $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Riemann integrable function, then $|f|$ is an integrable function also.

I understand the proof that
$$
\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x) + \epsilon
$$

but I need to translate this to
$$
\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)
$$
because otherwise the summations break down (see below). Can I just say that because $\epsilon > 0$ can be made as small as possible, then
$$
\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)
$$
in the limit? Once I have that, it's easy, because then I just sum the inequality across every interval to get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sup |f| - \inf |f|)(x_{i+1} - x_i) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sup f - \inf f + \epsilon)(x_{i+1} - x_i)
$$
which gives me the correct upper and lower sums. If I *can't* just remove the $\epsilon$, then I get
\begin{align}
U(|f|, P) - L(|f|, P) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sup |f| - \inf |f|)(x_{i+1} - x_i) \\
&< \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sup f - \inf f + \epsilon)(x_{i+1} - x_i) \\
\end{align}

where the supremum and infimum are taken over the interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$. I somehow need to prove that $U(|f|, P) - L(|f|, P) < \epsilon$, and I can't see how to manipulate that summation to do so.

EDIT: To clarify, I know that once I have
$$
U(|f|,P) -L(|f|,P) \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)
$$
the proof is complete because for any $\epsilon > 0$, I can pick a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$. My question is about using the supremum and infimum properties above to show that
$$
U(|f|,P) -L(|f|,P) \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)
$$
That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: If $a \le \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $a \le 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok, that's what I was missing then, since that's what lets me remove the $\epsilon > 0$. That $\epsilon$ comes from the proof in the [other answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/316095/93114) that led me to ask this question.

Comment: The proof will work either way, see my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get $U(|f|,P) -L(|f|,P) \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)$, and since $f$ is integrable, you can choose a partition so the right hand side is as small as you want. (Also, we have $0 \le U(|f|,P) -L(|f|,P)$.)

**Addendum**:

You have 
$\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$ for all intervals in a partition $P$. Hence
$\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|l(I)-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|l(I)\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)l(I)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)l(I)$.

Since (abusing notation a little, as in $I \in P$), and similarly for
$L(g,P)$, we have
$U(g,P) = \sum_{I \in P} \sup_{x\in I}g(x)l(I)$.

Hence $U(|f|,P) -L(|f|,P) \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)$.

Comment: Right, but my question is about how to show that $U(|f|,P) -L(|f|,P) \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)$. How does that follow from the supremum and infimum properties proved in my question and the one I linked to? That's what I'm stuck on. Once I have that, the rest is trivial (as shown in your answer).

Comment: Just sum the inequality (multiplied by the length of the interval) over all intervals in the partition.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but since the inequality is $\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x) + \epsilon$, I still get that $\epsilon$ *inside* the summation, which is what's causing trouble. How do I get rid of that $\epsilon$ so I just have $\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)|\le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$?

Comment: I am not sure why you are introducing an $\epsilon$ at that stage. Even if you do, when you sum it will be multiplied by $(b-a)$, and so can be taken to be arbitrarily small.